# WooCommerce - hide payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hide, payment

How I can hide a payment-gateway plugin for specific customer on WooCommerce , for example if the customer's first name is : Peter , the plugin will not show for him.

eg:
[Woocommerce hide payment gateway for user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770072/woocommerce-hide-payment-gateway-for-user-roles/33603803?noredirect=1#comment54983518_33603803)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will work for you , if any problem persist please let me know.

```
   function woo_disable_cod( $available_gateways ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        //check whether the avaiable payment gateways have Cash on delivery and user is not logged in or he is a user with role customer
        if ( isset($available_gateways['cod']) && ((current_user_can('customer') && $current_user->user_firstname == 'Peter' ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) ) {

            //remove the paypal payment gateway from the available gateways.

             unset($available_gateways['paypal']);
         }
         return $available_gateways;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'woo_disable_cod', 99, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Prafulla for the reply, unfortunately it didn't work with me .

I tied to edit the code but no result .

Comment: can you `var_dump( $current_user );` post what you got ?

Comment: this worked for me, just needed to properly adapt the condition to fit my case, the code is correct.